# Two WordPress sites sharing the same database

Tags: multisite, database

Here is what I'm looking to do.  I would like to set up two WordPress sites. 
The one site will be the production and the other site will be the staging.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the main site be used for production only, and the staging for development changes to make sure it works with the current data.

Comment: You definitely could do this, but no good can come from combining the databases.  Keep them separate.

Comment: Yes, nogood. Look for the Plugin: WP-Staging, it can do what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to use the same database. If you do your going to have all sorts of problems. With the biggest problem being you cannot have two different values for the site URL.

I would suggest a managed hosting solution such as [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io). This will provide you with a development, test, and live environment.

All code updates are made in your development environment. From there you deploy those changes to the test environment.

When deploying to the test environment, there is an option to pull in the database and media files from the live environment.

After thoroughly testing everything in the test environment. You'll deploy your changes to the live environment.

If everything was working in the test env. You can be certain that you didn't introduce any bugs in the live environment after you deployed.

The nice thing about Pantheon is you can spin up a new sandbox site for free. Once your ready to launch. You'll obviously have to switch to a paid plan.

If Pantheon is out of the question. I recommend recreating a similar workflow with your current hosting provider.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Can you state your affiliation, just to clarify, thanks.

Comment: I'm not employed by Pantheon. Nor do I receive any commission for referring anyone to their platform. I'm just sharing the best tool in our agencies arsenal when it comes to dev ops and workflow.

We are a recommended agency within their agency directory. But again, we receive no compensation for referring anyone to their platform. Here are the details for their agency program.

https://pantheon.io/agencies/developing-designs

https://pantheon.io/plans/partner-program